# External svg clip path doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am cropping a div container with svg clip path:

```
.element {
    ...
    clip-path: url("#clip-shape");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m08syex1/1/

It works for the svg code embedded inline in the HTML code. However, when I try to move the svg code outside in the crop.svg file:

```
.element {
    ...
    clip-path: url("../img/crop.svg#clip-shape");
}
```

It doesn't work in Chrome, however works in FF perfectly. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: works fine on my end on Chrome and FF. I was going to suggest browser specific prefix, but you have it in the jFiddle. Did you solve this by any chance?

Comment: Nope, the jsFiddle version works alright, but whenever I move the code to an external file, it doesn't work in Chrome

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109212

Comment: Then by process of elimination, your problem is not in this particular code, somewhere in your document, you have something conflicting. We need to see you reproduce the error. Try using the dev tool and hide/delete sections of the source until it's firxed, that will help you narrow down where the problem is

Comment: @LOTUSMS No, the problem is that the feature is not yet implemented in Chrome. See the above link for details.

Comment: Fair enough. I misunderstood

Comment: Thanks guys! Since it doesn't work in Chrome, I guess I have to comment out this line: -webkit-clip-path: url("#clip-shape"); to make it work with -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%); instead.